# How to easily wrap an entire (Redis) client

Tags: node.js, function, redis

No luck finding a previously asked question on this; wasn't entirely sure on how to phrase it.

Anyway, I'll start with the problem I'm trying to solve.
In our application we're caching data to Redis using the npm redis module. We initialise a client and make this available in our business logic and use it directly.
Now however, we want to encrypt the data we cache. So instead of having all the encryption/decryption logic in the main business logic, I was thinking it would be nicer if we could simply wrap the client so all calls would include an encryption/decryption step.
The issue is that the redis client has a whole heap of exported functions (set, hset, hmset, setex etc. etc. etc.), so it would be a pain to override/wrap each function individually.

So, my question is, is there a way to wrap the entire client? So that if any of the client's functions are called, a pre-process function is called that would perform the encryption/decryption beforehand, then call the redis client's own function.

E.g.

```
myClient.foo()
   call encrypt()
   call redisClient.foo()
```

but have the above occur automatically for every exported function of the redis client?

Again, this is early thinking so it might not even make sense to do this. Would need to determine certain behaviours dependent on certain functions; e.g. which calls encrypt, and which decrypt etc.
But, I suppose I was wondering if the above is even possible in a clean way? Even for a simple generic function like logging each client call or something that wouldn't be function dependent.

**Edit:**
Going to try and simplify what it is I'm thinking of doing.
If we take encryption out of the equation.
Is is possible to have a dynamically exported function name?
Something like the following, except "foo" is dynamic and can be used to call the redisClient exported function of the same name:

```
exports.myClient.foo = function(){ //where foo can be any value?
  genericFunction(arguments);
  redisClient[foo].apply(arguments)
}
```

Comment: I think it depends on how much you rely on the concurrency safety. If your crypto wrapper would expose your app to a race condition, then you'd miss the point. You can use Lua scripts, but AFAIK Lua does not help too much with encryption, and you'd have to wrap each method as you mentioned. Do you need to encrypt the data "in-transport" or "at-rest"?

Comment: The encryption is for resting data in the cache. We have the transport secured over TLS, but if the cache is compromised we want to have the contents encrypted. We're using Azure for our platform and are contemplating using KeyVault encryption services so the encryption would have to occur on the application side. This may change though as we're guessing the KeyVault encryption approach could have a significant performance hit as it's essentially an external http request.

Comment: On second thought, I can see no simple way of wrapping redis _without_ addressing each method separately. They have different params and behaviour, imagine the incrementation - do you safely increment encrypted data? If not, then you need the whole turnaround (get->decrypt->increment->encrypt->put), and still keep it atomic - then Lua is your only option I guess. How about keeping redis unaware and abstracting the encryption somewhere closer to the business logic? Maybe not all of it needs to be this secure?

Comment: Totally agree with @ptrk, I don't see no other way to address the specific requirements and behavior of every operation in a single universal way...

Comment: You have a good point with regards to not everything having to be encrypted in the cache so maybe a layer of abstraction might be better. With regards to having dynamic exported function names; if it can't be done then it can't be done :) Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is certainly possible and what you need to do is just take some time to create the class to wrap the redis client to add encryption. As far as I know, using the default client (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis), there is no easy way to have methods that can modify the input before it is stored into redis or the output before it is returned from a GET operation.

Assuming you are using redis only with SET and GET operations you can do something like this.

I am assuming you have your encryption logic in a specific module and that the encryption algorithm is synchronous:

```
// encryption.js

"use strict";

function Encryption(key) {
  this.key = key;
}

Encryption.prototype.enc(value) {
  // Encrypts the value using the key and returns it...
}

Encryption.prototype.dec(value) {
  // Decrypts the value using the key and returns it...
}

module.exports = Encryption
```

Our redis wrapper will look like this:

```
// encryptedRedisClient.js

"use strict";

function EncryptedRedisClient(redisClient, encryption)
{
  this.redisClient = redisClient;
  this.encryption = encryption;
}

EncryptedRedisClient.prototype.get(key, cb)
{
  this.client.get(key, function (err, reply) {
    if (err) {
      cb(err);
    }

    cb(null, this.encrypt.dec(reply.toString()));
  });
}

EncryptedRedisClient.prototype.set(key, value, cb)
{
  var encValue = this.encryption.enc(value); 
  this.client.set(key, encValue, cb);
}

module.exports = EncryptedRedisClient;
```

Finally you can use the wrapped client like this:

```
"use strict";

var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(); // add the needed options here
var Encryption = require('./encryption');
var EncryptedRedisClient = require('./encryptedRedisClient');

var encClient = new EncryptedRedisClient(client, new Encryption('some_secret_key'));

encClient.set(...);
encClient.get(...);
```

I haven't tested the code so there might be some minor issues, but this should give a pretty good starting point.

Comment: This approach still involves creating an exported function for each function in the redis client (the get and set functions). I'm looking for a way to have the encryption call happen on every exported function in the redis client, without having to manually write a wrapper for each one.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think the default redis module is offering an extension point to allow you to use a more generic approach. Also take in mind that every redis operation has its own internal logic and the way you will encrypt and then decrypt the information will change sensibly between operations. Just think about how you could encrypt/decrypt an INC operation (of course only if you want to encrypt counters as well which is not an easy assumption to make)...